# Construction of a triangle with ruler and compass

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-construction

Triangle constructions with ruler and compass can be very difficult. I have the following problem.
To construct a triangle given: the difference of side lengths b-c, angle A and angle B.

Comment: Not so difficult. 1) Angle C. 2) circle of any radius p. 3) x=p (sinB-sinC). 4) y=p sinA. 5) proportion (b-c)/x = a/y gives a.

Comment: Just draw any triangle with angles $A$ and $B$. Measure its $b-c$ and then enlarge/contract that triangle by the factor of $\frac{\text{required }b-c}{\text{observed }b-c}$. Of course, if $b=c$ then it is impossible if $2B+A\ne180^\circ$ and any triangle would do if $2B+A=180^\circ$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop It is nice idea to use homothety, but how do you actually construct the triangle? What is the center and coefficient of the homothety? The two triangles are clearly similar.

Comment: As $$\text{required }b-c:\text{observed }b-c=\text{required }c:\text{observed }c$$ this lets you construct the (required) length $c$, after which the rest is trivial. On the other hand, constructing the fourth length out of $x,y,z,t$ knowing the remaining three and the fact that $x:y=z:t$ is well-known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: ConstructionTriangle]

It is not that difficult to construct a triangle, given the angles at the vertices $A$ and $B$, and the measure of $b-c$. Without loss of generality, we assume that $b\gt c$. The case where $b = c\space$ is easy and, therefore, we do not discuss that in our answer. For brevity, we let the angles at the vertices $A$ and $B$ equal $\space\omega\space$ and $\space\beta\space$ respectively

We start the construction by drawing a line segment $PQ$, which is longer than $b-c$. Then, we mark points $B$ and $D$ so that $BD=b-c\space$ as shown in the diagram. Now, we need to construct the segment $BR$ so that $\measuredangle PBR=\beta$. After drawing the line $BS$ to make $\measuredangle SBD = \omega$, we construct its angle bisector $BT$. Next, the perpendicular from $D$ to $BT$ is dropped and extended to meet $BR$ at $C$. Drawing the line parallel to $BS$ through $C$ to cut $PQ$ at $A$ completes our construction.

Devising a construction is one thing and proving it is another. We would like to leave the job of compiling a sound proof of the above described construction to OP.

We add the following diagram at OP's request to chase angles. It clearly shows that $\triangle ADC$ is isosceles.

[image: AngleChase]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your construction is not correct. The triangle ADC should be isosceles by your construction but it isn't. Just chase the angles.

Comment: @martin We added a diagram showing the results of requested angle chasing to prove that $\triangle ADC$ is isosceles.

Comment: Thank you so much for your marvelous proof. The construction is now flawless.